# Why is my JS function executed onload instead of onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-events

Here's the code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    oldonload && oldonload();

    function test() {
        alert("meh");
    }    

    $('input[type=file]').change(test());
}
```

The code is fairly straight forward, `test()` is called only when `input[type=file]` is changed. However `test()` is being called whenever my page is **loaded**.

What is going on here? How would I execute the function only when user interacts with the input element?

Comment: It happens on load, because you said it so, use onclick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling the method on this line:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(test());
```

Change it to:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(test);
```

If you want to pass a parameter to `test`:

```
var myVar = 5;
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
   test(myVar); 
});
```

Comment: this is what happens when a backender is assigned to do frontend work....that worked perfectly thank you so much. I spent hours trying to figure it out!

Comment: Wait, then how would I pass a parameter to `test()`?

Comment: Then you could go with @DharaParmar's example using an anonymous function surrounding `test(myVar);`

Answer (score 2):

Just change the file change event like this :

```
 $('input[type=file]').change(function() { test() });
```

Comment: Parmer Thanks! +1 for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You're executing the function immedietaly instead of assigning a handler. You should instead do:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(test);
```

Comment: Thanks :) +1 for the prompt help!

Answer (score 1):

[change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) takes function as argument, so you just need to provide function name to be called.

```
$('input[type=file]').change(test);
```